# cordova couchbase-lite plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova, npm, ionic3, cordova-plugins

> Error: Text data outside of root node. Line: 94 Column: 13 Char: n at
>   error
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:666:10)
>   at strictFail
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:692:7)
>   at SAXParser.write
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1035:15)
>   at XMLParser.feed
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/sax.js:48:15)
>   at ElementTree.parse
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:271:10)
>   at Object.parse
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:584:8)
>   at Function.
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/cordova/config.js:35:28)
>   at Generator.next () at fulfilled
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62)

package.json

```
{
 "name": "dendronym",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "author": "Ionic Framework",
 "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
"clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
"build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
"ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
  "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
   "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.7.0",
  "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
  "@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
  "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
  "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
  "ionicons": "3.0.0",
  "rxjs": "5.5.10",
  "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
  "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",
"typescript": "~2.6.2"
 },
 "description": "An Ionic project",
 "cordova": {
  "plugins": {
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {}
  }
  }
  }
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>dendronym</name>
<description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
<author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />

<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="1.1.19" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="2.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
</widget>
```

This is the error I am getting while running the ionic cordova couchbaselite command.

Comment: can you please share the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Text data outside of root node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308808/error-text-data-outside-of-root-node)

Comment: Share package.json file and config.xml file